# compute start date of sub-date-range from given main date range in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

input is a main date range which is stored in myTbl.StartDate and myTbl.EndDate columns values.
for a given constant value as divider, I need to compute start date of sub-date-ranges gained from  dividing main date range to sub-date-ranges with constant value length.
examples are best explanations:
for main date range between '2017-1-1'  to '2017-1-22' and  const_val = 6 output is:

```
  2017-1-1 
  2017-1-7  (1 + 6) 
  2017-1-13 (7 + 6)
  2017-1-19 (13 + 6)
```

its noticable that the SQL user is not administrator(I can't use system tables)

Comment: First of all, it would be great if you could tag the dbms you are using (even if you mention that it's SQL Server). But another question: do you have some kind of calendar table? DimDate or something like this? And another thing: is it required to be in a single query or could you use a loop as well?

Comment: Please, show the expected result.

Comment: The expected result is listed above: 2017-01-01, 2017-01-07, 2017-01-13, 2017-01-19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive cte to do this:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE = '20170101' ,
    @endDate DATE = '20170122' ,
    @Const_val INT = 6;
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   @startDate AS DateVal
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   DATEADD(DAY, @Const_val, cte.DateVal)
               FROM     cte
               WHERE    DATEADD(DAY, @Const_val, cte.DateVal) <= @endDate
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte;
```

Produces:

```
DateVal
==========
2017-01-01
2017-01-07
2017-01-13
2017-01-19
```

The first part of the cte gets the first date:

```
SELECT   @startDate AS DateVal
```

Then it adds 6 days with the `UNION ALL` until the `WHERE` condition is met.

Comment: Looks pretty much the same as my solution. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = CONVERT(date, '2017-01-01');
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = CONVERT(date, '2017-01-22');
DECLARE @FixDateDiff int = 6;


WITH cte AS (
  SELECT @StartDate AS MyDate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, MyDate)
    FROM cte
    WHERE DATEADD(d, 1, MyDate) <= CONVERT(date, @EndDate)
)
SELECT MyDate
  FROM cte
  WHERE DATEDIFF(d, @StartDate, MyDate)%@FixDateDiff = 0
```

However, instead of the fixed dates I assigned to the variables, simply replace the variables with your StartDate and EndDate column and extend the cte accordingly.

Comment: you could just use the `@FixDateDiff ` value in the `DATEADD` instead of in the `WHERE` clause outside the cte for a simpler solution